# Laravel some questions (pagination, if - foreach)

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I'm laravel newbie. I'm created simple code and I have some questions:
I think this code bad (it works, but I use `@forelse($forums as $forum)` and anywhere use $forum)

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
@forelse($forums as $forum) <-- I don't like this line, it works but i think it's possible with if or something else
@forelse($topics as $topic)
{{ $topic->title }}<br>
@empty
Sorry but this forums empty.
@endforelse
@empty
Sorry but this forum not found
@endforelse
@stop
```

And second question how to make pagination? I'm tried this:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use View;

class viewForum extends Controller 
{
    public function showForum($fname, $fid)
    {
        return View::make('forum', [
            'forums'    => DB::table('forums')
                ->where('id', $fid)
                ->where('seo_name', $fname)
                ->select()
                ->get()
                ->simplePagination(5)
        ]);
    }
}
```

But not work's, I'm tried tutorials..etc, how to? Thanks so much in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first question. You can use @foreach or @each. these are the two that i usually used. 
for your second question:

```
return View::make('forum', [
            'forums'    => DB::table('forums')
                ->where('id', $fid)
                ->where('seo_name', $fname)
                ->select()
                ->paginate(5);
        ]);
```

remove ->get()

and replace simplePagination(5) with paginate(5)

documation http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination

**Update**

change you code block from

```
return View::make('forum', [
            'forums'    => DB::table('forums')
                ->where('id', $fid)
                ->where('seo_name', $fname)
                ->select()
                ->paginate(5);
        ]);
```

to

```
$forums = DB::table('forums')
                    ->where('id', $fid)
                    ->where('seo_name', $fname)
                    ->select()
                    ->paginate(5);
return View::make('forum', compact('forums'));
```

then check if $forums->render() got error.

**Update**

```
$forums = DB::table('forums')
                        ->where('id', $fid)
                        ->where('seo_name', $fname)
                        ->select()
                        ->get(5);
$topics = DB::table('topics')
->where('forum_id', $id)
->select()
->paginate(2)

return View::make('forums', compact('forums', 'topics'));
```

on your view you do `<?php echo $topics->render() ?>` since topic is the one you paginate. also you can remove ->select() from your code. if you don't specify fields to output.

Comment: Hmm thanks. I'm writed paginate(5) now prints 5results, but when I go to `http://example.com/forum/test-category/1?page=2` It prints `Sorry but this forum not found` :?

Comment: I'm deleted `@forelse($forums as $forum) and @empty
Sorry but this forum not found
@endforelse` now it works, but how can I now add this message if forum not found??

Comment: can you put more details of your code so i can properly understand what you're doing. I'm guessing you're passing parameters to your query. and it doesn't carry over when you click the next button. 
to append the parameters you need to add this to your renderer.

<?php echo $users->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->render(); ?>

documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links

Comment: i'm fixed it works. How can I add pagination buttons with pages?

Comment: put this to your view <?php echo $forums->render(); ?>

Comment: `Call to a member function render() on array`

Comment: how can I add to this code? http://i.imgur.com/0LWRHkh.png I have two variables, forums and topics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85082/discussion-between-dakine-and-evaldas888).

Answer (score 0):

For @foreach ($topics as $topic)

```
            {{$topic->title}}
          @endforeach
```

For Pagination

$users  = User::where('status','1')
                ->paginate(10);

Note: In View add this {{$user->links()}} for getting the pagination links.

Answer (score 0):

you can use @foreach() @endforeach and probably @if @else @endif
see sample:

```
@foreach($forums as $forum)
  @if($forum==0)
    {{'empty'}}
  @else
    {{ 'Not empty' }}
  @endif

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

for pagination i will suggest you use jquery datatable for proper pagination. Its quite okay and saves lots of time. see below the sample implementation:

```
//this preload the jquery library for datatable together with the print button
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

//this section call the document ready event making sure that datatable is loaded
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#').DataTable();
  } );

//this section display the datatable
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#mytable').DataTable( {
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          "pageLength": 5, //here you can set the page row limit
          buttons: [
              {
                  extend: 'print',
                  customize: function ( win ) {
                      $(win.document.body)
                          .css( 'font-size', '10pt' )
                          .prepend(
                              ''
                          );

                      $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                          .addClass( 'compact' )
                          .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
                  }
              }
          ]
      } );
  } );
</script>

//you can display record on the datatable as shown below
<div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
 <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
                                            <thead>
                                              <tr bgcolor="#c7c7c7">
                                                <th>S/N</th>
                                                 <th>Name</th>
                                              </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                            <tbody>

                                              @php
                                              $i=1;
                                              @endphp
                                                @foreach($queryrecord as $list)

                                                   <tr>
                                                   <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                                                   <td>{{ $list->name }}</td>
                                                   </tr>
                                               @endforeach
                                                </tbody>

                                          </table>
                                           <hr />
                                        </div>
```

Note: remember before displaying information on the datatable, you must have query your record from database.i'm using query builder here as sample

```
$data['queryrecord']=DB::table('tablename')->get();
```